# How to send page view location + referrer + user ip + user agent on GA4 with measurement protocol?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, measurement-protocol

I am trying to migrate my existing code from Universal Analytics to GA4.

This is the data I used to send using measurement protocol (not to be confused with JS library)

1. URL of page visited
2. User agent
3. Referral URL
4. User IP

This way, I could see the following details on GA.

1. Page view per user
2. Sessions per user
3. Location of user
4. User device info
5. URL of page viewed and the referal URL.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4

I follow this guide. But I am only able to send an event_name. It's missing rest of the data.

Answer (score 3):

The measurement protocol for GA4 is extremally limited at this time.  The team is opening up for new events slowly.

You should not expect to be able to send the hits you used to be able to send via the measurement protocol.

If you have a comments, or complaints please fill out [support form](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/support) its the only way we have to tell the team what they need to be focusing on.  I have been complaining about this alone for two years and im hoping if others like yourself start to complain maybe we can get it opened up faster.

Comment: Thanks. I am considering moving to [motamo](https://matomo.org/) now. They still support this feature

Comment: Measurement protocol is a complete headache, I don't know how Google could build such a horrible tool.

Comment: they are still working on it

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo If It's WIP, they shouldn't force everyone to switch to it

Comment: @VarunAgw you wont get any argument from me on that statement.